# ASP.NET Core strongly-typed options from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

There have been many changes to ASP.NET Core's "options" service. I'm using the latest version, and none of the tutorials and samples work anymore.

To keep it simple, I created a new ASP.NET Core web app, using Visual Studio's templates.

My `appsettings.json` contains:

```
"MyConfig": {
  "Foo": "Bar"
}
```

My strongly-typed config object:

```
public class MyConfig {
  public string Foo;
}
```

My `Startup.ConfigureServices` contains:

```
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<MyConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig"));
//services.Configure<MyConfig>(opts => Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig").Bind(opts));  // I also tried this
```

My `HomeController` contains:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

  private readonly MyConfig _myConfig;

  public HomeController(IOptions<MyConfig> myConfig) {
    _myConfig = myConfig.Value;
  }

  public IActionResult Index() {
    return Content(_myConfig.Foo);     // Foo is null
  }

}
```

And my `project.json` contains:

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
//"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder": "1.0.0",   // I also tried this
```

**But the `MyConfig.Foo` object is always `null`.**

Comment: I'm doing very similar and it works for me. I suggest try adding a get;set; on your Foo property, ie public string Foo {get;set;}  since that is one difference I see in your code

Comment: don't use rc2 as other person commented, it works in 1.0.0

Comment: Ohh yes it is not defined as property like Joe said

Comment: @JoeAudette That did it! Kinda obvious, as it's the basic model-binding approach in .net, but I made a copy-paste mistake. Please add it as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm doing very similar and it works for me. I suggest try adding a get;set; on your Foo field to make it a propertry, ie

```
public string Foo { get; set; }
```

since that is one difference I see in your code

Comment: Do you use the same `project.json` references as I do above? There is no guidance anywhere about which to use. I'm working on the basis of removing everything, and if it doesn't crash then it's okay.

Comment: yes, I'm using the same, for IOptions you definitely need Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions as you have it. if you are not using user secrets you could remove that one, environment variables also is optional but can be useful for production or azure deployment.